# MSSQL - WHERE LIKE a part of a string

Tags: sql-server

if i hava a variable

> ```
> declare @tag nvarchar(max) = '1570,20342'
> ```

and I wanna select a data ,her field "tag" value is

> "1443,1570,3245,20342"

this value is string, and was combined by "1570" and "20342",

how to select that data out ?

Comment: I would split data by comma and then you can make equal or what you want

Comment: Did you try using like statement in sql

Comment: the like statement doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery to get the string stored in the variable:

Example:

```
DECLARE @tag NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @tag = '1570'

SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE COLUMN LIKE (SELECT '%'+@tag+'%')
```

You won't be able to search for both values in a column without splitting them first. You could do this by using two variables, like:

```
DECLARE @tag1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @tag1 = '1570'

DECLARE @tag2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @tag2 = '20342'

SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE COLUMN LIKE (SELECT '%'+@tag1+'%')
     OR COLUMN LIKE (SELECT '%'+@tag2+'%')
```

Although this is a quick workaround for this situation, it does not scale well and the only way to fix this would be to normalize your tables, stop using more values separated by commas on one row, instead use one value per row.

Comment: Why `LIKE (SELECT '...')` and not just `LIKE '...'`? Anyway, this is unreliable, because `LIKE '%1570%` would match not only `'...,1570,...'` but also e.g. `'...,21570,...'`.